# Wygwam & CKeditor wordcount

Tags: wygwam

I'm looking to use the [wordcount](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount) plugin for the CKeditor in WYGWAM.  Wordcount states it is compatible with version 4 of CKeditor, which is in v3 of WYGWAM.  So my question is - Is it possible to get wordcount working inside of WYGWAM 3?  Can anyone confirm before I buy a licence?

Comment: Did you end up giving this a shot? Did it work?

Comment: Not yet Nick, I should have time to try next week, watch this space.

Answer (score 1):

I can can confirm this works.  Here are the steps I took.

1. Copy old WYGWAM folders out of themes/third_party & expressionengine/third_party to somewhere safe
2. Copy New folders in respective places.
3. In admin Go to Addons/Modules and click Run Module Updates (top right)
4. In same screen click WYGWAM, and clone and existing config (the one you use)
5. Click new cloned version, under "Advanced Settings" select extraPlugins from the dropdown and type "wordcount" in the text box (sans quotes).
6. At this point my WYGWAM field was broken because it was trying to init old ckeditor plugins, namely channel images, you may or may not get this problem depending on your setup but if you do, copy missing plugins (console.log shows whats missing) from the ckeditor/plugins folder backed up in step one, into the new folder (these plugins are in the theme area).

That's it, I wanted to have a word and character count so I edited  themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/plugin.js and changed the defaultConfig var accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used that particular extension (Wordcount) with Wygam, I have had success using a few others, so it should theoretically work. If it doesn't, Devot-ee has a 30 day return policy.